# MAPE is producing inf as the output

Tags: python, data-science, linear-regression

I am using MAPE metric for my linear regression model. The output is `inf`.

The code looks like this:

```
import numpy as nm

def MAPE(a, b):
    mape = nm.mean(nm.abs((a - b) / a)) * 100
    return mape

MAPE(data.iloc[:, 1], pre)
```

`pre` is the variable storing the predicted value.

Can anyone suggest what is the glitch in this ?

Comment: `x/a` is `inf` whenever `a` is `0.0`

Comment: You should include code that is minimally reproducible so that others can easily help you. You should also state what values you are using for variables a and b. Looking at what you have it seems that a and b are taking on identical values and causing division by 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @filbranden wrote correctly in his comment - when any of your real values is equal to zero, your code returns `inf` because of zero division. Take a look at my simple test with different real values and predicted values for computing MAPE. Here is the `pandas.DataFrame` called `data`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'real_1': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
        'real_2': [100, 100, 100, 100, pd.np.nan],
        'real_3': [100, 100, 100, 100, 0],
        'pred_1': [110, 130, 120, 105, 100],
        'pred_2': [110, 130, 120, pd.np.nan, 100],
        'pred_3': [110, 130, 120, 105, pd.np.nan],
    }
)
print(data)
   real_1  real_2  real_3  pred_1  pred_2  pred_3
0     100   100.0     100     110   110.0   110.0
1     100   100.0     100     130   130.0   130.0
2     100   100.0     100     120   120.0   120.0
3     100   100.0     100     105     NaN   105.0
4     100     NaN       0     100   100.0     NaN
```

I used your `MAPE(a, b)` function to compute MAPE.

```
for real_val_col in ['real_1', 'real_2', 'real_3']:
    for pred_val_col in ['pred_1', 'pred_2', 'pred_3']:
        real_val = data[real_val_col]
        pred_val = data[pred_val_col]
        print(f'- MAPE for {real_val_col} and {pred_val_col}: {MAPE(real_val, pred_val):.2f} %')
```

And here is the test result. You can see, that MAPE is equal to `inf` in all the cases, where program had to divide a non-missing value by zero.

```
- MAPE for real_1 and pred_1: 13.00 %
- MAPE for real_1 and pred_2: 15.00 %
- MAPE for real_1 and pred_3: 16.25 %
- MAPE for real_2 and pred_1: 16.25 %
- MAPE for real_2 and pred_2: 20.00 %
- MAPE for real_2 and pred_3: 16.25 %
- MAPE for real_3 and pred_1: inf %
- MAPE for real_3 and pred_2: inf %
- MAPE for real_3 and pred_3: 16.25 %
```

Comment: If the case you are stating is true, then which error metrics should i use to verify the accuracy of my data ?

Comment: @SrijanSrivastava, you can try to use [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).